# Flutter: SQLite database in external storage. database is null

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I am writing an app to store some events and dates at which events happened (For history students as part of a project). I wish to create an SQLite database, stored in some preferred location in my device. Later I want this database to merge with main database using computer. Here is my database helper class;

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  static final _dbName = 'mainDatabase.db';
  static final _dbVersion = 1;
  static final _mainTable = 'mainTable';
  static final _storyTable = 'storyTable';
  static final _topicTable = 'topicTable';
  static final columnId = '_id';
  static final title = 'title';
  static final description = 'description';
  static final parentId = 'topic_id';
  static final priority = 'priority';
  static final iconId = 'iconId';
  static final futureImage = 'image';
  static final year = 'year';
  static final month = 'month';
  static final day = 'day';
 DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static Database _database;

Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database;
    }
    _database = await _checkPermission();
    return _database;
  }

  var status;
 _checkPermission() async {
    this.status = await Permission.storage.status;
    debugPrint(' storage permission status  : ${this.status}');
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      _initiateDatabase();
    } else if (await Permission.storage.request().isUndetermined) {
      debugPrint('Undetermined permission');
    } else if (await Permission.storage.request().isDenied) {
      debugPrint('Permission denied');
      _checkPermission();
    } else if (await Permission.storage.request().isPermanentlyDenied) {
      debugPrint(' it has been permenantly denied');
      
    }
  }
_initiateDatabase() async {
    debugPrint(' database initialized');
    Directory directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

    String path = join(directory.path, _dbName);
    debugPrint('Path for database: ${path}');
    return await openDatabase(path, version: _dbVersion, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }
Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''

      CREATE TABLE $_mainTable (

        $columnId INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        $year INTEGER,
        $month INTEGER,
        $day INTEGER,
        $title TEXT NOT NULL, 
        $description TEXT,  
        $priority INTEGER,
        $parentId INTEGER,
        PRIMARY KEY($columnId AUTOINCREMENT)
         );   
           
      '''); /
 Future<int> insertEvent(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    debugPrint(' event  : ${row}');
    assert(db != null);                           //Issue!!!!
    return await db.insert(_mainTable, row);
  }

}
```

*My code may seem messy, because I am not from this background. I apologize for that.*

When I tried to add an event I get this error;

```
I/flutter ( 8090): event id is null
I/flutter ( 8090):  storage permission status  : PermissionStatus.granted
I/flutter ( 8090):  database initialized
I/flutter ( 8090):  event  : {year: null, month: null, day: null, title: adsfasdf, description: null, priority: 0, topic_id: null}
E/flutter ( 8090): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:thisDay/config/databaseHelper.dart': Failed assertion: line 189 pos 12: 'db != null': is not true.

    /////////////// some code

E/flutter ( 8090):
I/flutter ( 8090): Path for database: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.thisDay/files/mainDatabase.db
```

What should I do? I am stuck at this point. I have my db file at `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.thisDay/files/mainDatabase.db` . But can't add anything in it.
Any help would be greately appreciated.

*Nb:- At first I used getApplicationDirectory instead of External directory. There were no issues. I have to switch because of portability issues*

Answer (score 0):

for creating a database and table you can refer this code

```
Database database;

  opendatabase() async {
// Delete the database
    String databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, "sample.db");
    // await deleteDatabase(path);

    database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      // When creating the db, create the table
      await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE tbl_test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sample TEXT, code TEXT, format TEXT)',
      );
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fixed my issue by myself. `_initializeDatabase()` has a return type `Future<Database>`. So making respective changes on code fixed my issue.

```
Future<Database> _checkPermission() async {
    this.status = await Permission.storage.status;
    debugPrint(' storage permission status  : ${this.status}');
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      return await _initiateDatabase();
    } else if (await Permission.storage.request().isUndetermined) {
      debugPrint('Undetermined permission');
    } else if (await Permission.storage.request().isDenied) {
      debugPrint('Permission denied');
      _checkPermission();
    } else if (await Permission.storage.request().isPermanentlyDenied) {
      debugPrint(' it has been permenantly denied');
    }
  }

  Future<Database> _initiateDatabase() async {
    debugPrint(' database initialized');
    Directory directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

    String path = join(directory.path, _dbName);
    debugPrint('Path for database: ${path}');
    return await openDatabase(path, version: _dbVersion, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }
```